# Delete referenced rows in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

In my mySQL database, I have a field `uniqid` in a table called `discussions`. This id is the unique id for that certain discussion. In another table `discussion_replies` I have the field `discussion_id` which is the discussion the reply is under.

Is there a way to delete all replies with a `discussion_id` when a row in `discussions` is deleted just in mySQL, or can this only be done within PHP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: MySQL triggers is what you seek http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html

Comment: What database engine are you using? MYISAM or INNODB?

Comment: See this on `FOREIGN KEY Constraints` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: Cheers guys for the rapid responses, great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just use relations:

```
ALTER TABLE `discussion_replies` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk` FOREIGN KEY (`discussion_id`) REFERENCES `discussions`(`uniqid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Before running this query make sure you have same columns with same type in both tables.

Comment: Tried a similar sql query, was missing the constraint value, this worked great. Thanks!

Comment: The answer is correct, but this called a *foreign key constraint*, not a *relation*.  [The word "relation" is actually another word for "table" though the two are not precisely identical in definition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_(database)) and relational databases are so-named because data is stored in normalized tables -- not because of the relationships between rows across tables based on foreign keys, though this is a common misconception.